# Show additional result database values on click - UPDATED WITH SOLUTION

Tags: php, jquery, search, mysqli

I'm new to PHP/Mysql and am trying to learn through some online tutorials. One thing I can't seem to figure is this.

I am able to search my mysql database for results with the usual `SELECT` command, and display the results in a table, each row representing one matching database entry and all the associated columns:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|id      |part    |price   |model   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|1       | a      | 10     | X1     |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|2       | b      | 20     | X2     |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|3       | c      | 30     | X3     |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
and so on...
```

But how can I separate things, such that my results only include the `id` and `part` at first, with the `price` and `model` only shown, say within a textarea, after the user clicks on a search result? This way they don't need to view a ton of data, but can review some relevant additional information on the search matches that they are interested in? Each search clicked can update the textarea to show only that result's additional data. Do I need to include some javascript/jquery to bind the click event, or can it all be done within PHP?

Thanks.

**UPDATED SOLUTION THAT WORKED FOR ME**

> As suggested below, I did the following: 1) tacked on a
>   `class='.rowselect'` for the `<TR>` in my search result to bind a
>   click event 2) also added an id with the column id when generating my
>   search result table

Used this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $('.rowselect').click(function(){

    var sel_id = $(this).attr('id');
$.post("reported.php", //URL of the page on server
        { // Data Sending With Request To Server
        rowid: sel_id
        },
        function(data,status){ // Required Callback Function
        $('.output').val(data); // textarea has class output
    });
});
});
```

and the PHP for `reported.php`

```
  // $conn to database first, then ...
  // $name= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['rowid']);//-query the database table
  $sql="SELECT price, model FROM db_name entry_id=".$name.";";
  //-run  the query against the mysql query function
  $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  echo "Price: ".$row['price'] ."\n\nModel: ". $row['model'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initially call the first two columns only with your SELECT statement and display it in your Table, the results in your Table can be shown as links, and when the user say, clicks on an ID, you can make a POST request to a method on server side(PHP) which will respond with the additional data for the clicked ID, you can then populate it in a textarea.

example:

```
//Send a POST request with id or part
$id = (int) $_POST['id'];
$query = "SELECT price,model from your_table where id= ?";
//more PDO stuff
```

Comment: Okay - so I can use jQuery to bind a click event within the table, capture the `id` or `part`, and send it to a POST request using `jQuery.post()`? I think this example would allow me to do what you recommend right? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ - Thanks!

Comment: I fiddled around with using $.post to send the click event, bound to the `id` and returned a sql search from this `id` as you suggested! Worked great. Thanks.